# angualrjs, find duplicate as input validation with ng-repeat , ng-form nested under form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

i am trying to find duplicate value enter in textbox which check each input value on ng-change.then show message "sos number has a match".tried this one but still sort make list data in order. resulting, regular message [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkhxkozp/8/)
so far i am unsuccessful. following is code. :

html code:

```
<form name="settingForm" ng-submit="mangeDeviceSettings()"><div class="form-group"> 
                                 <div data-ng-repeat="i in sosLength track by $index">
                                 <ng-form name="sosNumForm">
                                    <span class="input-icon"> <input type="text" ng-disabled="!showPendingStatus" watch-change="change()"
                                      class="form-control" name="SOSNumber"  ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="13" placeholder="SOSNumber{{$index+1}} No." ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"
                                      ng-model="deviceSettings.sos[$index]" ng-change="sosChange($index,this)">
                                      <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>
                                      <span ng-show="IsMatch{{$index}} && sampleSOS && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$dirty">SOS Number has a match!</span>
                                      <span ng-show="(sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.minlength || sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.maxlength) && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$dirty">Mobile Number must be between 10 and 13 digits </span>
                                      <span ng-show="!sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.minlength && !sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.maxlength && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.pattern && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$dirty">Number must contain only numbers</span>
                                  </ng-form>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div></form>
```

ng-change method:

```
$scope.sosChange=function(idx, obj){
    $scope.sampleSOS = true;
    $scope.fnfDuplicate=true; 
    obj.$parent.settingForm.$valid = obj.sosNumForm.$valid;
    // console.log(obj.$parent.settingForm.$valid); 
    // console.log(obj.sosNumForm.$valid);
    console.log($scope.deviceSettings.sos[idx]);
    console.log($scope.deviceSettings.sos[i] );
    // console.log(obj.sosNumForm.$valid);
    //  console.log($scope.deviceSettings.sos[idx]!="");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(idx != i ){
            if ($scope.deviceSettings.sos[idx] == $scope.deviceSettings.sos[i] 
                && obj.sosNumForm.$valid && $scope.deviceSettings.sos[idx]!="") {                    
                if(idx==0){
                    $scope.IsMatch0=true;  $scope.sosDuplicate=true;               
                    return false;
                }
                if(idx==1){
                    $scope.IsMatch1=true;  $scope.sosDuplicate=true;               
                    return false;
                }
                if(idx==2){
                    $scope.IsMatch2=true;  $scope.sosDuplicate=true;               
                    return false;
                }                    
            }
            else{
                if(idx==0){
                    $scope.IsMatch0=false;  $scope.sosDuplicate=false;
                    return false;
                }
                if(idx==1){
                    $scope.IsMatch1=false;  $scope.sosDuplicate=false;
                    return false;
                }
                if(idx==2){
                    $scope.IsMatch2=false;  $scope.sosDuplicate=false;
                    return false;
                }
            }  
            // $scope.sosDuplicate=true;               
        }                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you simply want to have a validation that two fields have the same value... like password and confirm password... Ill paste a snippet with that (its for password and confirm password) but from there Im sure you can get what you need

I also dont see a need for ngChange since the two items are in the scope so you just want to do a validation if they are not equal.

```
<div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : changePasswordForm.password.$invalid && submitted}">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">New Password </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minLength="6" type="password" required>
            <p ng-show="changePasswordForm.password.$error.minlength && submitted" class="help-block">Password must be atleast 6 characters long.</p>
            <p ng-show="changePasswordForm.password.$error.required && !changePasswordForm.password.$error.minlength && submitted" class="help-block">Password is required.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : (changePasswordForm.confPassword.$invalid || user.password!== user.confPassword) && submitted}">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="confPassword" ng-model="user.confPassword" type="password" required>
            <p ng-show="changePasswordForm.confPassword.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">This field is required.</p>
            <p ng-show="changePasswordForm.confPassword.$valid && user.password!== user.confPassword && submitted" class="help-block">Passwords must match.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and submitted is for checking when submitted... not required

so here you see we check if the two scope items are not equal and accordingly we show the error...

in the controller all you need is

```
$scope.onSubmit = function () {
        $scope.submitted = true;
            if ($scope.createProfileForm.createUserForm.$valid && $scope.user.password === $scope.user.confPassword) {
                $scope.submitted = false;

            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, for answering but, unlike your answer you check one time matching value password .where i am checking each time all other text-field with inputed text-field for duplicate and show corresponding message.BTW i found work around this: https://jsfiddle.net/pkhxkozp/8/

Comment: I dont see how that changes the answer... you update the scope...  so make a function that returns true or false if the scope items are different... and remove the submitted... that way its updated on each scope change... the answer still stands

Answer (score 0):

html code:

```
<div class="form-group"> <!-- <div data-ng-repeat="i in sosLength track by $index"> -->
                                 <div data-ng-repeat="i in persons track by $index">
                                 <ng-form name="sosNumForm">
                                    <span class="input-icon"> <input type="text" ng-disabled="!showPendingStatus" watch-change="change()"
                                      class="form-control" name="SOSNumber"  ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="13" placeholder="SOSNumber{{$index+1}} No." ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"
                                      ng-model="deviceSettings.sos[$index]" ng-change="sosChange(this,deviceSettings.sos[$index])">
                                      <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>
                                      <!-- <span ng-show="IsMatch{{$index}} && sampleSOS && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$dirty">SOS Number has a match!</span> -->
                                      <span ng-if="i.isDuplicate"> SOS Number has a match!</span>
                                      <span ng-show="(sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.minlength || sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.maxlength) && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$dirty">Mobile Number must be between 10 and 13 digits </span>
                                      <span ng-show="!sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.minlength && !sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.maxlength && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$error.pattern && sosNumForm.SOSNumber.$dirty">Number must contain only numbers</span>
                                  </ng-form>
                                </div>
                              </div>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.sosDuplicate=true; 
$scope.fnfDuplicate=true; 

$scope.persons = [{sos:""},{sos:""},{sos:""}];
$scope._persons = [{fnf:""},{fnf:""}];

$scope.fnfValid = true;
$scope.sosValid = true;

$scope.sosChange=function(obj,value){
    var sorted, i;
    var count =0, checker;

    // obj.$parent.settingForm.$valid = obj.sosNumForm.$valid;
    $scope.sosValid = obj.sosNumForm.$valid;
    if(value!="undefined" || value != "")
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            checker = parseInt($scope.deviceSettings.sos[i]);
            $scope.persons[i].sos = checker==NaN ? "" : checker;
        };


        sorted = $scope.persons.concat().sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.sos > b.sos) return 1;
            if (a.sos < b.sos) return -1;
            return 0;
        });

        for(i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {                    
            sorted[i].isDuplicate = ((sorted[i-1] && sorted[i-1].sos == sorted[i].sos) || (sorted[i+1] && sorted[i+1].sos == sorted[i].sos)
                || (sorted[i+2] && sorted[i+2].sos == sorted[i].sos)|| (sorted[i-2] && sorted[i-2].sos == sorted[i].sos));

            if(sorted[i].isDuplicate==true){
                count+=1;
                console.log(count);

            }
            $scope.sosDuplicate= (count>1) ? true : false;

        }

    }
}
```